# Google Cloud Platform Deployment 502 Bad Gateway nginx. Flask, gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

I am currently trying to deploy my Grocery Store Management System on Google Cloud Platform. I am new to GCP and wanted to learn how to deploy a CRUD application on this platform. However, I am running into a problem where I get the following error:

```
2023-08-19 07:23:21 default[20230819t222222]  "GET /getProducts HTTP/1.1" 502
2023-08-19 07:23:51 default[20230819t222222]  [2023-08-19 07:23:51 +0000] [11] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:15)
2023-08-19 07:23:52 default[20230819t222222]  [2023-08-19 07:23:52 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Worker (pid:15) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
```

I have ran mprof on the said problem, and it appears that the memory usage remains constant.

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    40     35.9 MiB     35.9 MiB           1   @app.route('/getProducts', methods=['GET'])
    41                                         @handle_db_connection
    42                                         @profile
    43                                         def get_products(connection):
    44     35.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       products = products_dao.get_all_products(connection)
    45                                         
    46     35.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       if "error" in products:
    47                                                 return jsonify(products), 500
    48                                         
    49     35.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return jsonify(products)


127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2023 16:31:13] "GET /getProducts HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I am really confused about what to do since when I run it locally using "gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py server:app" it runs normally. Below are the app.yaml, requirements.txt and gunicorn_config.py.

app.yaml

```
runtime: python311

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT server:app

resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 4
  
env_variables:
    DB_USER: root
    DB_PASSWORD: root
    DB_HOST: 11.11.111.111
    DB_NAME: grocerystore
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.3.2
Flask-Cors==4.0.0
mysql-connector-python==8.1.0
python-dotenv==1.0.0
gunicorn==21.2.0
```

gunicorn_config.py

```
import os

# Use 2 workers per CPU core for optimal performance
workers = 2 * (os.cpu_count() or 1)

# Bind to all available network interfaces on port 8000
bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"

# Set the timeout to 30 seconds
timeout = 30

# Log requests to stdout
accesslog = "-"

# Log errors to stdout
errorlog = "-"

# Set log level (debug, info, warning, error, critical)
loglevel = "info"

# Use the sync worker class
worker_class = "sync"

# Set the graceful shutdown timeout
graceful_timeout = 10

# Set the keep-alive timeout
keepalive = 5

# Set the maximum number of requests per worker
max_requests = 1000

# Limit each worker to 100MB of memory
worker_memory_limit = '100M'
```

The code in that is the problem:
server.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, make_response
from flask_cors import CORS
from DataAccess import products_dao, orders_dao, uom_dao
from sql_connection import get_mysql_connection
import functools

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

# Decorator to handle database connection and response for each route
def handle_db_connection(route):
    # Necessary for 'add_products' to update the inner function's metadata
    @functools.wraps(route)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        connection = get_mysql_connection()
        if connection is None:
            return jsonify({"error": "Database connection error"}), 500
        
        try:
            # Call the original route function with the database connection
            result = route(connection, *args, **kwargs)
            
            return result
        
        except Exception as e:
            error_response = {
                'error': 'An error occurred while processing the request.',
                'details': str(e)
            }
            response = make_response(jsonify(error_response), 500)
            return response

        finally:
            connection.close()

    return wrapper

# PRODUCTS
@app.route('/getProducts', methods=['GET'])
@handle_db_connection
def get_products(connection):
    products = products_dao.get_all_products(connection)

    if "error" in products:
        return jsonify(products), 500

    return jsonify(products)
```

products_dao.py

```
#Products
import mysql.connector

def get_all_products(connection):
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # SQL query to retrieve all products along with their uom information
            query = ("SELECT products.product_id, products.name, products.uom_id, products.price_per_unit, uom.uom_name "
                     "FROM grocerystore.products INNER JOIN grocerystore.uom ON products.uom_id = uom.uom_id")
            cursor.execute(query)

            response = []
            for (product_id, name, uom_id, price_per_unit, uom_name) in cursor:
                # Append each product to the response list in a dictionary format
                response.append({
                    'product_id': product_id,
                    'name': name,
                    'uom_id': uom_id,
                    'price_per_unit': price_per_unit,
                    'uom_name': uom_name
                })

            return response

    except mysql.connector.Error as e:
        raise Exception("Error executing MySQL query:", e)
```

sql_connection.py

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import mysql.connector
import os

load_dotenv()

def get_mysql_connection():
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            user= os.environ['DB_USER'],
            password= os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'],
            host= os.environ['DB_HOST'],
            database= os.environ['DB_NAME'],
        )
        return connection
    except mysql.connector.Error as e:
        print("Error connecting to MySQL:", e)
        return None
```

GCP Logging:

```
124.39.123.1 - - [21/Aug/2023:00:39:15 -0700] GET /getProducts HTTP/1.1 502 674 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "strong-skyline-396215.an.r.appspot.com" ms=31508 cpu_ms=168 cpm_usd=0 loading_request=0 instance=00c61b117c17e06295f84baaddad39fe1ad20974843f21ae955d5c8e16f710c322f7199df2fb6ae60a7a94c4c9390184d2ad58d2afb764512716 app_engine_release=1.9.71 trace_id=cf2272a2bf2b786234c07095db1a85a9
{
httpRequest: {1}
insertId: "64e314c2000aeff62321a01d"
labels: {1}
logName: "projects/strong-bayfine-396222/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log"
operation: {4}
protoPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog"
appEngineRelease: "1.9.71"
appId: "b~strong-bayfine-396222"
endTime: "2023-08-21T07:39:46.716661Z"
finished: true
first: true
host: "strong-bayfine-396222.an.r.appspot.com"
httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1"
instanceId: "00c61b117c17e06295f84baaddad39fe1ad20974843f33ae955d5c8e16f710c322f7199df2fb6ae60a7a88c4c9390184d2ad57d2afb764512716"
instanceIndex: -1
ip: "124.33.333.3"
latency: "31.508585s"
megaCycles: "168"
method: "GET"
requestId: "64e314a300ff032189f2682ec40001627e7374726f6e672d736b796c696e652d3339363231350001323032333038323174313633373131000100"
resource: "/getProducts"
responseSize: "674"
spanId: "13794630510933683298"
startTime: "2023-08-21T07:39:15.208076Z"
status: 502
traceId: "cf2272a2bf2b786234c07095db1a85a9"
urlMapEntry: "auto"
userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
versionId: "20230821t163711"
}
receiveTimestamp: "2023-08-21T07:39:46.719862170Z"
resource: {2}
spanId: "13794630510933683298"
timestamp: "2023-08-21T07:39:15.208076Z"
trace: "projects/strong-bayfine-396222/traces/cf2272a2bf2b786234c07095db1a85a9"
}
```

Desired Output:

```
[{"name":"Pok\u00e9ball","price_per_unit":200.0,"product_id":1,"uom_id":1,"uom_name":"each"},{"name":"Great Ball","price_per_unit":600.0,"product_id":2,"uom_id":1,"uom_name":"each"},{"name":"Ultra Ball","price_per_unit":1200.0,"product_id":3,"uom_id":1,"uom_name":"each"},{"name":"Potion","price_per_unit":300.0,"product_id":4,"uom_id":1,"uom_name":"each"},{"name":"Super Potion","price_per_unit":700.0,"product_id":5,"uom_id":1,"uom_name":"each"},{"name":"Hyper Potion","price_per_unit":1500.0,"product_id":6,"uom_id":1,"uom_name":"each"},{"name":"Max Potion","price_per_unit":2500.0,"product_id":7,"uom_id":1,"uom_name":"each"},{"name":"Full Restore","price_per_unit":3000.0,"product_id":8,"uom_id":1,"uom_name":"each"},{"name":"Revive","price_per_unit":1500.0,"product_id":9,"uom_id":1,"uom_name":"each"}]
```

Is there any other way to solve this? Thank you :)

Comment: 1) In Cloud Run use 1 worker per CPU. CPU allocation is vCPUs not cores. 2) Your issue is `WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:15)`. Your post does not show what your code does, but something is taking too much time, is waiting too long for an external resource, or is hung in a loop.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you very much for your response.  I have just updated the question.

Comment: Which service are you running the code on? Your code is printing errors as they occur. What does Cloud Logging show?

Comment: @JohnHanley I am running the code on GCP's app engine using google cloud build API. I have put the logging in the questions right above. Thank you very much

Comment: I meant the entries your program is printing that are stored in Cloud Logging.

Comment: @JohnHanley There is nothing other than the logging I have given before is it possible it is due to the SQL database on GCP?